# Functions, domains and codomains

Tags: functions, notation

I am refreshing a bit my basic knowledge of mathematics, and I have some doubts, I am sure you can help me with.

Let's take this function in python:

```
def f (x): return x ** 2
```

I gather that this can be written as:

$$f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R \\
x \mapsto x^2$$

Both domain and codomain of this function are $\Bbb R$.

How about this function:

```
def g (f, x):
    def h (y): return x * f (y)
    return h
```

Assuming that $f$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, and that both $x, y \in \Bbb R$, how do I write this python function in mathematical notation.

I think I can figure out the domain and codomain:

$$
g: \Bbb R ^ \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R ^ \Bbb R\\$$

But how do you express the actual function mapping?

Comment: What do you mean "the actual function mapping"? I think your boxed text explains the mapping $g$ very clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(f,x)\mapsto (y\mapsto x\cdot f(y))$

Answer (score 2):

Note you can also do an iterated pointwise definition:

$$ g(f,x)(y) := x f(y) $$